# Is it possible to use a telerik bootstrap 3 theme in an angular 2+ application?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui

I'm using a customized Bootstrap 3 theme in my Angular 2+ application, together with Telerik's Angular 2 components. The default Telerik theme does not match well with Bootstrap, so I wanted to use the official Telerik Bootstrap theme instead. The problem is, that the "official" Bootstrap theme for Angular is for the Bootsrtap 4 version, which is not compatible with my Bootstrap 3 skin.

Since bootstrap 4 is still Alpha, I really don't want to upgrade my project either.

Kendo for JQuery support Bootstrap 3, so I've tried to use the css from there by including the complete Kendo JQuery folder in my app, and referencing the css like this in my scss by replacing:

```
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all";
```

with

```
@import "assets/content/kendo/css/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css";
@import "assets/content/kendo/css/kendo.bootstrap.min.css";
@import "assets/content/kendo/css/kendo.dataviz.min.css";
@import "assets/content/kendo/css/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css";
```

It was absolutely not working unitl I have added the default angular theme reference back above the v3 files.

Now things started to work more or less, like popups have changed, but grid filters icons became misplaced. I have found workarounds for some of the glitches, but I'm not sure if I'm just wasting my time on sg. that is not meant to be working at all.

So is there an out of the box solution to use Bootstrap 3 themed Kendo components in an angular app? Or maybe I'm wrong about Bootstrap 4 and it's already OK for production use?